# How to set a default value for a site-column of type managed metadata in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, managed-metadata, site-column, taxonomy

Is there any way to set a default value for a site-column of type managed metadata in SharePoint 2010 programmatically using C#?

I have come accross the following code, however, it throws "array out of bound..." error for wssId.

```
 TermSet termSet = null;
            Term term = null;
            TaxonomySession currentSession = new TaxonomySession(newBuiltSite);
            var termStore = currentSession.TermStores["Managed Metadata Service"];
            var group = termStore.Groups["Code Group"];
            termSet = group.TermSets["Code"];
            term = termSet.Terms[siteCode];
            int[] wssId = TaxonomyField.GetWssIdsOfTerm(newBuiltSite, termStore.Id, termSet.Id, term.Id, false, 1);
            TaxonomyField field = newBuiltSite.RootWeb.Fields["Code"] as TaxonomyField;
            field.SspId = termSet.TermStore.Id; // termStore.Id;
            field.TermSetId = termSet.Id;
            field.TargetTemplate = string.Empty;
            field.AnchorId = Guid.Empty;
            field.DefaultValue = wssId[0].ToString() + ";#" + term.Name + "|" + term.Id.ToString().ToLower();
            field.Update();
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you map the site column to term set, edit the site column to set its default value.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Deepmala! However, I need to do it programmatically using C#, sorry for not posing my questing clearly, I have just updated my question.